# Column value merging in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to perfom column value merging in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your JSON

```
var jsonData = [
                  {
                    "bucket": ">120",
                    "productCodes": ["SBML", "SBHL"]                  
                  },
                  {
                    "bucket": "1-30",
                    "productCodes": ["SBHL", "SBML", "SBML+"]
                  },
                  {
                    "bucket": "X",
                    "productCodes": ["SBNL++"]
                  }
                ];
```

and you view

```
<body ng-app="myApp">       
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" align="center">  
        <table border="1">
            <tr>

                  <th>Bucket</th>   
                  <th>PRODUCT_CODE</th>              
                  <th>Allocated #</th>                   
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in products">

                  <td><span>{{p.bucket}}</span></td>                                     
                  <td><span ng-repeat="c in p.productCodes">{{c}}</span></td>
                  <td><span>{{p.productCodes.length}}</span></td>                     
            </tr>               
        </table>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u please help me in making such a json ... i tried with underscore but could not.. may be my approach was incorrect.. but thanks in advance.